# Removing Top Margin for Mobile with CSS

Tags: css

I have the top margin added to move down some widgets down that are stuck under another graphical element. On mobile, these widgets move to the bottom of the page (instead of the sidebars).

How do I remove the additional top margin css I added to move down the widgets:

```
.widget_peepsowidgetlatestmembers {

    margin-top: 300px;
    }
```

This moves them down, but I need to remove this for tablet and mobile screens cuz it's a waste of space. Thanks!

Comment: Look into CSS media queries

Comment: You can look into [`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), though in general the *reason* for needing such a high value for a `margin-top` should be looked into; it's very unusual to have such a requirement, and will likely cause other issues.

Comment: Ditto. This is simple, but if you're using margins to move items, then you need to have a better handle on your development.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I hear you. Just learning and I had to deal with theme restrictions. It works great now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can apply css rules on specific range of screen width (eg. 0 to 768px wide)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .widget_peepsowidgetlatestmembers {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the tips. Had to make a fudgecicle cuz of the theme restrictions. It looks great on all devices now. Grazie!!